# What is the equivalent C# 3.0 Linq to SQL for this?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, vb6, c#-3.0, transactions

Old VB6 Code that needs to be converted:

```
'DB Connection
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Conn.ConnectionString = sConn
Conn.Open sConn
Conn.BeginTrans

'Recordset
Set rsPrice = New ADODB.Recordset
rsPrice.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsPrice.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rsPrice.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
rsPrice.ActiveConnection = Conn
```

What would be the exact equivalent of this in C# .NET 3.5 Linq to SQL?  I remember reading somewhere that using System.Transactions would require having MTS on the backend, but my memory is fuzzy this morning.

**EDIT:**

I could not find a direct match for CursorLocation, CursorType, and LockType up with the new APIs, which is the source of my confusion.  I am familiar with TransactionScope, but I do not know if the defaults of TransactionScope are acceptable or if I'm making a bone-headed mistake by trusting in them.  The database is SQL Server 2005.

Comment: It mostly depends on the type of transaction you are trying to do. Unfortunately you've not really given enough details to explain what you're trying to accomplish. If you make a new console project in Visual Studio and add a Linq-To-Sql file to it, then drag some tables from your database on to the designer you should be off to a good start.
We use transactions in ours without MTS running, but we use MS SQL Server. Transactions are built into .net

Comment: are you looking for the transactionscope?

Comment: specifically I'm looking to match up CursorLocation, CursorType, and LockType up with the new APIs.  This may be a rat hole, as the defaults are probably fine.  I just want to avoid a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically your VB6 is actually a bit suspect.  When you set CursorLocation to Client-side then CursorType has no impact.  It is only relevant for server-side cursors.

See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261297) KB article to prove that I'm not talking out of my hat!

My understanding is that LinqToSQL requests bring all the data to client. They do not use server-side cursors at all.  Therefore, the behaviour of LINQ should be the same as your VB6 code.  The only thing you might want to look into is there is a way in ADO to control how the optimistic locking detects update conflicts.  You can use timestamp, changed fields or all fields.  I'm not sure how LINQ handles update conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Using System.Transactions requires MSDTC (Microsoft Distributed Transaction Controller) not MTS.

If you can swallow that requirement, then you can do something like this:

```
using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope scope = new
System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
   try
   {
      //todo: do your linq to sql here

      //commit it, everything is successfully done!
      scope.Complete();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DataContext comes with a constructor that accepts a connection.  I think you can manage your transaction as it has been managed before.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292288.aspx

> If you provide an open connection, the DataContext will not close it. Therefore, do not instantiate a DataContext with an open connection unless you have a good reason to do this.

Also, we've used System.Transactions without the Distributed Transaction Coordinator.  You only need that if your transaction covers multiple database servers (multiple connections).